# Why is my Discord bot that only responds to a specific message in a specific channel not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Here's the code I wrote:

```
    bot.on('message', (message) => {
    // your messages should go into this array
    const messages = ["honk", "mess with the honk, you get the bonk", "*inhales*   HONKKKK", "*steals your keys*", "*steals your glasses*", "*steals slippers*", "peace was never an option", "*steals knife*", "*rips anti-goose sign down*", "*waddles into blm protests and attempts to chant along*", "never gonna honk you up", "never gonna honk you down", "never gonna honk you up, never gonna honk you down", "https://tenor.com/view/goose-honk-inhale-inhales-untitled-gif-16237480", "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zqR5pqTjqwM/maxresdefault.jpg", "https://media1.tenor.com/images/320ce00cc388ba92de7757f0458e4ad4/tenor.gif?itemid=16337290", "https://media1.tenor.com/images/6db3d9f7cb1165a0dacd6a9bb4b4af89/tenor.gif?itemid=16627067", "https://nintendowire.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/GooseHonk.gif", "https://media1.giphy.com/media/Jp3v0iCuOI3vpCFvf4/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e4729rv9siv12yp6agxx7tcfhw2pncoghn3cfaqh9yy&rid=giphy.gif", "https://media4.giphy.com/media/xT39CZ1aM1WB0dZwOY/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e4727230bb427e31469bbd225ca01dbf99c5253f1dc&rid=giphy.gif", "https://tenor.com/view/goose-gif-5452772", "https://tenor.com/view/goose-birds-moves-dance-shake-gif-5453425", "https://tenor.com/view/goose-silly-funny-waddle-funny-walk-gif-16307417", "https://marcus.is-inside.me/asqhvav1.png", "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/737982177765228614/739026340346331166/image0.png", "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/737169801566224434/740210286849687612/image0.jpg", "https://marcus.is-inside.me/hgaNlUNZ.png", "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/740466394361233468/755986396929327236/ZNFMTWerFYngqFZatJG9MM-1200-80.png"]
    const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        let prefix = 'honk';
        if (message.channel.name === "honk") {
            if (String(message.content.toLowerCase()) == 'honk') {
                chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
                if (chance == 0) {
                    console.log(`${message.author.tag} hit the jackpot!`)
                    return message.channel.send("h0nk")
                } else {
                    console.log(`${message.author.tag} honked!`)
                    return message.channel.send(randomMessage);
                }
            } else if (String(message.content.toLowerCase()) == 'h0nk'){
                chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
                if (chance == 0) {
                    console.log(`${message.author.tag} hit the jackpot!`);
                    return message.channel.send('*chuckles* || HONKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK ||');
                } else {
                    message.delete();
                }
            } else {
                message.delete();
            }
```

I'm trying to get the following command to work in the #honk channel:

```
    } else if (String(message.content.toLowerCase()) == ("honkhelp")) {
    console.log(`${message.author.tag} sent honkhelp`)
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("help")
        .setDescription("commands for honkers")
        .setColor("#14ff2c")
        .addField("honk", "well, just say honk!")
        .addField("honkguilds", "check how many guilds the bot is in!")
        .addField("honkpics", "a random goose picture!")
        .addField("requirements", "please make a channel called `#honk` for honkers to work! [please check our troubleshooting page](https://[link])")
        .addField("support server", "[click here](https://discord.gg/GxfQh7H)")
        .addField("other info", "do `honkabout`")
        .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL({ type: "png", dynamic: true, size: 2048 }))
        .setTimestamp();
    // help embed
    return message.channel.send(embed);
```

Instead of it responding to the message (and deleting the original message), it deletes the message and doesn't send the embed. How can I make it keep the user message and send the embed?

Source code: https://github.com/inkthought-labs/honk

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of it responding to the message (and deleting the original
> message), it deletes the message and doesn't send the embed. How can I
> make it keep the user message and send the embed?

Let's look at the flow of your code

```
if (message.channel.name === 'honk') {
  // code here
} else if (String(message.content.toLowerCase()) == 'honkhelp')) {
  // send embed help message here
}
```

Since you are trying to use the `'honkhelp'` command in the channel named `'honk'`, the code will execute the first `if` and won't enter in any `else` / `else if`.

Side note: use `===` instead of `==` (you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons))

If you want to prioritize the help message over the usual honk answer, move the block of help in the `if` and put the rest in the following `else if`
You can also move this block in an `else if` after the the `if (message.channel.name === "honk")`